# How do you increase # of self-hosted parallel jobs on Azure DevOps Services using an associated VS Enterprise subscription?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a Visual Studio (formally MSDN) ***Enterprise*** License.

My newly created Azure DevOps Service does not reflect this when looking at the self-hosted pipeline configuration under **Project Settings > Pipelines > Retention and parallel jobs**.

[image: Appropriate section of parallel jobs configuration]

According the the (i) info button:

> Visual Studio Enterprise subscribers get one self-hosted parallel job
>   as a subscriber benefit.

Anyone know how I can get my Enterprise Subscription to show through to Azure DevOps Services (formally VSTS)? It was pretty simple to do with TFS, but am drawing blanks on ADOS.

My user account for both my Enterprise account and ADOS are one and the same - I was rather hoping it would just show through - apparently that's not the case.

The best I found was [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-pipelines-tfs?view=tfs-2018#use-your-visual-studio-enterprise-subscription-benefit) page - but it's only for TFS and explicitly warns that:

> The requested page is not available for Azure DevOps Services. You have been redirected to the newest product version this page is available for.

My initial attempt at asking MS through their online chat "Concierge Service" was met with apathy and a suggestion I ask elsewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently patience ***is*** a virtue.

It took several days but eventually (or was it because I also raised this issue on the [Azure Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/374763/associated-vs-enterprise-subscription-not-showing.html) site?) it correctly shows my associated Enterprise Subscription.